# LISP: Help reading input stream (with spaces) into a list of characters

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am attempting to write a program whereby I need to process a string character-by-character, including whitespace.  This string would be given by the user running the program, from the standard input stream.

I have noticed that the `(read)` function stops only after some non-whitespace characters have been captured, and cuts off everything starting with the first whitespace character.

In other words if I do a `(read)` function and enter `hi to you`, it will return `HI`.  What I would like my function to return is `(#\h #\i #\Space #\t #\o #\Space #\y #\o #\u)`.  Can anyone give me some pointers as to how to accomplish this?  Sorry guys, I am VERY new to LISP but I like it a lot.

EDIT: One thing I've tried is using (cons) with (read-char).  For example: `(cons (read-char) (cons (read-char) (cons (read-char) (cons (read-char) (read-char)))))`.  When the user enters "hello", this outputs `(#\h #\e #\l #\l . #\o)`, which is close, but what is that extra period doing in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[read-char](http://l1sp.org/cl/read-char) will return the next available character, and [read-line](http://l1sp.org/cl/read-line) will return an entire line of input as a string. You can use [coerce](http://l1sp.org/cl/coerce) to change a string to a list of characters, e.g.

```
(coerce "foo" 'list) => (#\f #\o #\o)
```

Answer (score 5):

Xach basically answered your main question: you'd probably want to read a line with `read-line` and coerce it to a list: `(coerce (read-line) 'list)` and then do something with this list.

The reason that `read` doesn't work is that it reads and returns s-expressions:

```
> (car (read))
(foo bar baz) ; this is me typing

FOO
```

So it just reads the first symbol `hi` in the input "hi to you" and stops. Successive calls to read will return the rest:

```
> (list (read) (read) (read))
hi to you ; me typing again

(HI TO YOU)
```

You probably still want to use Xach's suggestion to get your input though.

To address your other question, the reason there's a dot in that list of characters is that the expression `(cons (read-char) (cons (read-char) (cons (read-char) (cons (read-char) (read-char)))))` ends with `(cons (read-char) (read-char))` which conses two characters together.

Cons creates "cons cells" or Lisp pairs, which are represented as a dotted pair:

```
> (cons 'a 'b)
(A . B)
```

Lisp lists are usually formed with `nil` or the empty list as the last element. But they are actually represented as linked lists with these cons cells, these are the same:

```
(a . (b . (c . ())))

(a b c)
```

They are just usually printed the second way. In your case, the last element is a character, so it's printed as a dotted tail list. Experiment with it at the REPL and it will make sense:

```
> '(a . (b . c))
(A B . C)

> '(a b . c)
(A B . C)

> '(a b c)
(A B C)

> '(a . (b . (c . nil)))
(A B C)
```

So what you would want to do with that original expression is this:

```
> (cons (read-char) (cons (read-char) (cons (read-char) (cons (read-char) (cons (read-char) nil)))))
(#\h #\e #\l #\l #\o)
```